# Variables $X_n$ have PDF: $g_n(x) = (n+1)x^n $ on $x \in (0,1)$ . Show that seq. $X_n$ converges by prob. to some const. Does it conv. a. s. or $L^1$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are defined on a common probability space. For $ \ n = 1, 2, (...) \ $ the variable $X_n$ has a distribution with density function $g_n(x) = (n+1)x^n \ \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}$ . Show that the sequence $X_n$ converges by probability to some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Does it also converge almost certainly to this constant? Does convergence in $L^1$ occur?

My idea (that is clearly not good and I don't understand why):

From a given PDF I can calculate CDF:
$ f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x (n+1) t^n \ dt = \int_{- \infty}^0 (n+1) t^n \ dt + \int_{0}^x (n+1) t^n \ dt = \int_{0}^x (n+1) t^n \ dt = x^{n+1}$

From that I can calculate convergence in dinstribution:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^{n+1} = 0$$
for: $x \in (0,1)$.

Therefore I know that the limit is a constant, but it's $0$ and I don't know if that's not bad, because there is no random distribution equal to $0$.

If the limit was a constant different than $0$, then convergence in dinstribution would imply convergence in probability and we would know that the seqence is convergent to some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ in probability.

Edit:

In response to some suggestions, I don't know why would it be true that $F_X(x) \to 1$ when $n \to \infty$. As I calculated above, I think the CDF is $x^{n+1} \ \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}$. "Looking at all values" as sugested in the comments doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

Comment: Hint: start by sketching the pdf and the CDF _for all_ $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$ for $n = 1, 2$ to get a feel for what the CDF function looks like instead of confining your attention to just $x \in (0, 1)$.  What is the CDF function converging to?n Remember to look at _all_ values of $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$....

Comment: For almost sure convergence, consider the convergence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_n-1|>\varepsilon)$ for $0<\varepsilon<1$ and the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: @Math1000 I liked the idea presented in the only answer, but I don't know how to calculate CDF on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ line since the integral that I get is equal to $- \infty$ :(

Comment: Hint: $\int_{-\infty}^0 f_n(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Math1000 I don't get it at all. Why would I integrate from $ - \infty$ to  $\infty$ if $x \in (0,1)$? Additionally, I literally can not integrate on that set to not get infinity.

Comment: @Math1000 if you understand that, could you show me just that integral so I can think why it works that way and move on from that? I've been stuck on that for 2h and I don't know how that works anymore. I just don't and I won't get it by looking 20h more.

Comment: @mathman12 You do integrate over the whole real line...but $f_n(x)=0$ unless $x\in(0,1)$, so...

Comment: @Math1000 But if I take the integral of PDF over the whole $\mathbb{R}$ line I get $1$ for every PDF, because by the very definition the area under that function must be equal to $1$. So that's obvious that $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) = 1$. But that doesn't give me anything since I am looking for CDF.

Comment: $F_n(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_n(t)\mathsf dt$

Answer (score 1):

The constant is $1$. Indeed,

$$\mathbb P\left[\left|X_n - 1\right|\ge \varepsilon \right] = (1-\varepsilon)^{n+1} \to 0$$

It also converges in $L^1$ since

$$\mathbb E\left[X_n\right] = \frac{n+1}{n+2}\to 1$$

Comment: Ok, but why my idea with PDF $\to$ CDF did't yield the same result? Secondly, how did you find out that the constant is $1$? Did you just guess? Thirdly, in your definition of convergence by probability $1/2$ would work as well, so why do we choose $1$? Additionally, I'm not sure that you read CDF in the correct way (I think there should be $1- P()$). I don't understand the last line also.

Comment: Finding the constant $1$ is easy if you look at the CDF of $X_n$ on the whole line $\mathbb R$ and not only in $(0,1)$ (which is the mistake in your argument). No my argument doesn't work for $\frac12$ because in that case the probability will not go to $0$. The last line is just computing the expectation. Do you know how to compute expectation using the PDF?

Comment: I don't see how CDF converges to $x = 1$. I edited the question to bring the image. Could you write some more in the line with $\mathbb{P}$? Maybe I just don't see the transformation. For expectation I usually use $\mathbb{E}X = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \cdot f(x)$, where $f(x) is the CDF. I don't see how that applies here.

Comment: Your images are incorrect as the expression of $x^{n+1}$ is only valid for $x\in(0,1)$. For the expectation, it applies here because you are looking for the $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: Oh, Now I get it. I was looking at a wrong function. I had wrong CDF.

Comment: but when I calculate $\int_{- \infty}^x (n+1) t^n dt$ I get $- \infty$. How to find CDF for the whole $\mathbb{R}$ line?

Comment: You need to use the expression only when it is valid.

Comment: it's not valid on $\mathbb{R}$. Then which expression should I use to find CDF?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146601/discussion-between-youem-and-mathman12).