# Let's say $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables with finite varinace. Is a squence of $X_n = I_{(|Y| \leq 2n)}Y + I_{(|Y| > 2n)} Z^2$ convergent in $L^1$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let's say $Y$ and $Z$ are random variables with finite varinace.

$$X_n = I_{(|Y| \leq 2n)}Y + I_{(|Y| > 2n)} Z^2$$

*Where $I$ = indicator function (I can't compile latex if I write "$1$".

Now, I would like to know if a sequence of random variables $X_n$ convergent in probability. Does it converge a. s. or in $L^1$. What's the limit of the sequence if that limit exists?

---

I thought about using the Kologomorov's strong law of large numbers for random variables with alternating distributions, because the distribution of $X_n$ will change depending on $Y$ being larger or smaller than $2n$

Therefore we have to check if its true that:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{Var(X_n)}{n} < \infty$$

We know that if the varince of Y is finite, then there is some $ 0 \leq k \leq n$ such that when we go with n to infty: $\forall n> k: |Y| \leq 2n$. Therefore we can write that:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{Var(X_n)}{n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{Var(Z^2)}{n} + \sum_{n = k+1}^{ \infty} \frac{Var(Y)}{n} = Var(Z^2) \sum_{n = 1}^{k} \frac{1}{n} +  Var(Y) \sum_{n = k+1}^{ \infty} \frac{1}{n} $$

As we see from that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{Var(X_n)}{n}$ is in fact finite. Therefore we can conclude that by SLLN the sequence of $X_n$ is convergent a. s. That implies that it is also convergent in probability. But how can I tell if it converges in $L^1$ or find it's limit?

Comment: $(|Y| \leq 2n)$ increases to the whole space and $(|Y| > 2n)$ decreases to the empty set. You are making a moutain out of a mole hill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite trivial. No Theorem is required. The first term tends to $Y$ a.s. and the second term tends to $0$ a.s.. So $X_n \to Y$ a.s.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thank you for that. @geetha290krm

Comment: actually, since you understand probability very well, could you tell me why $CDF = 1$ in one of my prevous questions? I get it $x^{n+1}$ and I don't understand why that's bad. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716418/variables-x-n-have-pdf-g-nx-n1xn-on-x-in-0-1-show-that-seq?noredirect=1#comment9990616_4716418

Comment: @mathman12 Your computation there is valid only for $0<x<1$. For $x \geq 1$ the limit is $1$. There is a unique CDF which has the value $0$ for $x<1$ and $1$ for $x \geq 1$. This corresponds to the constant random variable $1$.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!